# DBeaver multiple selects in one tab

Tags: database, dbeaver

I would like to have multiple select statements in one tab.

***I will give a example.***

SELECT * from TableA

SELECT * from TableB

SELECT * from TableB

***Result I would like to see:***

Result from table A

Result from table B

result from table C

Is it possible to have something like that? I dont want to open multiple tabs, I would like to have multiple results in one tab in text mode.

Answer (score 5):

Just click this button:

[image: Execute script button]

or <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd>

Comment: That worked - upvoted. Interesting enough, you cannot use `alt` + `enter`, which works for multiple `SELECTS` that point to the same database, but different tables.

Answer (score 0):

I also need an answer for this: I want the results from several different queries, all in only one single tab, in text mode.

If that is not possible, getting all results logged to a single text file on the client filesystem will work too.

Comment: Sorry , I know it's not an answer. But stackoverflow didn't allow me to post a comment before, for some reason..